# Слайдер owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

Возможно ли сделать слайдер с такой галереей http://prntscr.com/jazjm3 плагином owl-carousel? Если да, можно примерный код такого слайдера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-cont {
  width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.owl-carouse div {
  width: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-dot {
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#1f1f1f, #000000);
  background: radial-gradient(#1f1f1f, #000000);
}

.owl-carousel {
  text-align: center;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  outline: 4px solid red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

      items: 1,


    });
  });



  jQuery(document).ready(function() {



    dotcount = 1;

    jQuery('.owl-dot').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).addClass('dotnumber' + dotcount);
      jQuery(this).attr('data-info', dotcount);
      dotcount = dotcount + 1;
    });

    slidecount = 1;

    jQuery('.owl-item').not('.cloned').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).addClass('slidenumber' + slidecount);
      slidecount = slidecount + 1;
    });

    jQuery('.owl-dot').each(function() {

      grab = jQuery(this).data('info');

      slidegrab = jQuery('.slidenumber' + grab + ' img').attr('src');
      console.log(slidegrab);

      jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(" + slidegrab + ")");

    });

    amount = jQuery('.owl-dot').length;
    gotowidth = 100 / amount;

    jQuery('.owl-dot').css("width", gotowidth + "%");
    newwidth = jQuery('.owl-dot').width();
    jQuery('.owl-dot').css("height", newwidth + "px");



  });
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

<div class="slide-cont">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div><img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav1-1.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav2-1.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav3-1.png"></div>
    <div> <img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav4-1.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

и оказывается есть есть красивее решение :[codepen.io/pen/thumbnails+owl/](https://codepen.io/aykutkapisiz/pen/POGJxg?q=Owl%20Carousel%202%20Thumbnails&limit=all&type=type-pens)